# How i can add one more value to my varray list in a column in pl/sql?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I'm trying to add one more value to my varray list of numbers called `burse` using multiset union all but I get this error.  [[image: Istoric is my column name and bure is the type (varray of numbers)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDW3G.png)

But when I insert a single value its working. Example:[image]

What I am doing wrong ?

This is how I declare and insert into column [image]

Comment: Screenshots are Teh Suck! Nobody can recreate your problem without typing all your DDL for themselves. You're asking a bunch on strangers on the internet to help you, so why not make it easier for them by posting your code **as text** which they can quickly cut'n'paste into an IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

```
update student 
set istoric = istoric multiset union all bure(42, 23) 
where id = 1
```

... except that you're now using a VARRAY (and not the nested table you had [in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49464584/146325)). So you get an error message:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got BURE

The reason is, [according to the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjcol.htm#CHDGGJBF):

> "While nested tables can also be changed in a piecewise fashions, varrays cannot....However, you cannot **update or delete individual varray elements directly with SQL**; you have to select the varray from the table, change it in PL/SQL, then update the table to include the new varray." (emphasis mine)

This is because VARRAYs are ordered sets while Nested Tables are not. Unless there is a firm requirement to maintain the order of elements it is better to use Nested Tables rather than Varrays: they're just more convenient.

So here is how you can update a Varray using PL/SQL:

```
declare
    lv bure;
    cnt pls_integer;
begin
    select istoric into lv
    from student
    where id = 1;

    cnt := lv.count();
    lv.extend();
    lv(cnt+1) := 23 ;
    lv.extend();
    lv(cnt+2) := 69 ;

    update student
    set istoric = lv
    where id = 1;
end;
/
```

Comment: You want to say :                                                                         update student 
set istoric = istoric multiset union all burse(42, 23) 
where id = 1 ? This is what i try in first photo and its not working for me .

Comment: Yeah. You didn't post revised DDL for these tables so I'm using the type and table I created for your previous question, and editing it. Anyway, I revised my answer following your edits to the question.